# Can an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ be homeomorphic to a subset that contains some of its boundary?

Tags: general-topology

Consider $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the usual Euclidean topology, or the (equivalent) product topology. Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be open. Suppose that $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is such that $V \cap \partial V \neq \emptyset$. Can there possibly exist a homeomorphism $h : U \to V$?

I have been thinking about this problem for a little while. My intuition is telling me that, no, such a homeomorphism cannot exist. After all, since $V \cap \partial V \neq \emptyset$,  $V$ contains a few of its "edge" or boundary points. But, since U is open, it contains nothing of the sort. Certainly this property of being an "edge" or boundary point should be preserved (in some way) through homeomorphism?

Is there a basic topological argument that puts this question to rest, or a more advanced theorem that needs to be applied? I'm hoping we don't have bring forth the Jordan Curve Theorem here.

Hints or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The answer is "No, there can't be a homeomorphism". It's the invariance of domain, if a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, it is itself open. I know no elementary or non-advanced proof, however.

Comment: In this exact case, the answer is "no", because you forgot the case when $U$ is connected and $V$ is not. If you add the hypothesis that both $U$ and $V$ are connected, take for (counter-)example the unit ball and the punctured unit ball.

Comment: @Daniel: Isn't this a complete answer? Why do you post this as a comment?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I was hoping that somebody with a better recollection of algebraic topology could give a sketch of a proof.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thanks for the comment! I don't have a great understanding of algebraic topology, but at least I know where the proof comes from now. I should eventually have a look in Munkres about homotopy theory :)

Comment: @GustavoMarra: The unit ball and the punctured unit ball are not homeomorphic, but both are connected.  I'm not sure what your claim is.

Comment: My claim comes in two parts: He didn't assume that $U$ and $V$ are connected; in this case it is easy to proof that they are not necessarily homeomorphic. If it is assumed connectedness, then take U the unit open ball centered at the origin and V the open unit ball centered in the origin minus the origin. They are not homeomorphic and therefore his claim is false.
Now, thinking about it, my example with balls is valid wether $U$ and $V$ are connected or not, so no arguement about connectedness is needed :-)

Comment: @GustavoMarra: He didn't make the claim that they must necessarily be homeomorphic, he just asked if it's possible that two such sets are homeomorphic.  Giving examples where they're not doesn't prove that such sets can *never* be isomorphic.

Comment: Also, neither of your example sets intersect their boundary, so what is $V$ in your example?

Comment: I mistook $V\cap \partial V\neq \emptyset$ for $V\cap \partial V= \emptyset$ and I'm sorry for the confusion :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theorem on the invariance of domain says that if $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is open, and $f \colon U \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a continuous injective function, then $f$ is open, in particular $V = f(U)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $f$ is a homeomorphism from $U$ to $V$.

So if $V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is homeomorphic to an open $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, then $V$ itself must be open - the homeomorphism provides a continuous injective function $U \to \mathbb{R}^n$.

I know of no proof of the theorem of invariance of domain that does not use advanced techniques, unfortunately.